# createDataPartition for several columns in caret package

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, r-caret, knn

I'm trying to find the optimal k-value using `caret` package to run a KNN algorithm. My data looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaNdj.jpg) (`datanet` on the code) with `"ACTIVITY_X"`, `"ACTIVITY_Y"` and `"ACTIVITY_Z"` being my predictors as I want to classify `"Event"` based on the values from columns B to D. All columns have the same number of rows.

For that, I first need to split the data for cross-validation. Here's a sample of my code:

```
# Split the data:

indxTrain <- createDataPartition(y = datanet$ACTIVITY_X,p = 0.8,list = FALSE)
training <- datanet[indxTrain,]
testing <- datanet[-indxTrain,]

# Run k-NN:
set.seed(400)
ctrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",repeats = 3)
knnFit <- train(Event ~ ., data = training, method = "knn", trControl = ctrl, preProcess = c("center","scale"),tuneLength = 20)
knnFit

#Use plots to see optimal number of clusters:
#Plotting yields Number of Neighbours Vs accuracy (based on repeated cross validation)
plot(knnFit)
```

My questions are two:

1) If I understand correctly when using `caret` package, the `y` argument in  `createDataPartition` needs to be the predictor variable right?

2) If so, I have three predictors as mentionned earlier (`"ACTIVITY_X"`, `"ACTIVITY_Y"` and `"ACTIVITY_Z"`), but if I'm running `createDataPartition(y = datanet$(ACTIVITY_X, ACTIVITY_Y, ACTIVITY_Z)p = 0.8,list = FALSE)` I'll get an error message.

Any ideas on how to use `createDataPartition` for cross-validation when predictor data includes several columns?

Would it be ok to just run `createDataPartition` with just one predictor (let's say `"ACTIVITY_X"`) as the partition then will apply to the rest of the columns?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not gather all targets into a single column? Otherwise, you may fit several models independently. I assume by "predictors" you mean the target.

Comment: By "predictors" I mean a feature and by "response" I mean a target (or class). I'm trying to classify events (column E) based on the value of columns B to D. Does that make sense?

Comment: We split by "outcomes" ie target not predictors. I've added a simple explanation in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split your data according to the target variable not the predictors. That is:

```
indxTrain <- createDataPartition(y = datanet$Event,p = 0.8,list = FALSE)
```

Here's why from `?createDataPartition`:

> y
>   a vector of outcomes. For createTimeSlices, these should be in chronological order.

Comment: Thanks. And the run the algorithm with my target in argument as well?              `knnFit <- train(Event ~ ., data = training, method = "knn", trControl = ctrl, preProcess = c("center","scale"),tuneLength = 20)`

Comment: Yes Exactly like that. BTW you can accept an answer and/or upvote if it helps solve your problem. You should do the same for past questions too.

Comment: Done! @desertnaut @akrun @NelsonGon. @NelsonGon, as for the parameter `set.seed(400)` when running the algorithm, does it need to match the number of rows of my input table? I know this function will be generating a random set but was wondering if 400 would just be a rule of thumb value.

Comment: You can use any number. I normally use 233. It's just for reproducibility.

Comment: Thanks again. However, I see that `repeats` is "used for repeated k-fold cross-validation only" and represents "the number of complete sets of folds to compute". Does this correspond to the number of sets of predictors?

Comment: The partitioned data is further subdivided into sets defined by the "number" argument. If you use repeatedcv in the method argument, then the cross validation is repeated as defined by "repeats."